# Corresponding real iDevice and iOS simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, xcode5

I feel a little dummy to ask such a question but I am not sure. Can someone tell me to whichreal  device corresponds exactly each device in the simulator? I have seen [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/iOS_Simulator_Guide/GettingStartedwithiOSStimulator/GettingStartedwithiOSStimulator.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012848-CH5-SW1) that all the devices available in the simulator are the following ones, but to what do they correspond?

```
iPhone Retina (3.5-inch) :iPhone 4 and 4s?

iPhone Retina (4-inch) : iPhone 5?

iPhone Retina (4-inch 64-bit) : iPhone 5s?

iPad

iPad Retina : iPad 1, 2 or 3?

iPad Retina (64-bit)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the iPhone entries you have are correct.

5th gen iPod touch would be under iPhone Retina 4".

4th gen iPod touch would be under iPhone Retina 3.5".

The 3rd gen and earlier would be under iPhone Non-retina 3.5"

The iPad would be:

iPad - iPad 1, iPad 2, 1st gen Mini

iPad Retina - iPad 3, iPad 4,

iPad Retina 64-bit - iPad Air, 2nd gen Mini

I find the Wikipedia page [List of iOS devices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_iOS_devices) to be very helpful.